# ORA-01034: ORACLE not available on remote connection

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

When I try to connect to Oracle database from the remote host (I use oracle instant client), I get following errors:

```
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3640
Additional information: 1108778635
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

However, `ORACLE_HOME` on the host machine is set correctly, as well as `ORACLE_SID`, and i can easily connect to the database from its host machine:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Jul 10 09:20:09 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: system
Enter password:
Last Successful login time: Wed Jul 10 2019 09:13:57 +03:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options
```

What can cause this sort of behavior?
UPD:
Status of the listener on the remote DB:

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.71.2)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                05-JUL-2019 08:56:16
Uptime                    6 days 23 hr. 29 min. 47 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/log/diag/tnslsnr/epyc-gbu2/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.71.2)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "AGRO.GBUBDD.RU" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "AGRO", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
```

UPD2:
The command I use to connect to remote DB:

```
sqlplus /nolog
connect system/oracle@192.168.71.2:1521/agro.gbubdd.ru
```

Comment: Please share the command, you are using from the remote machine to connect to the Oracle database.

Comment: After I launch SQL *Plus, I use `connect <login>/<password>@<host>:<port>/<global_database_name>`

Answer (score 0):

This could happen due to 2 reasons. 
1) Oracle database is not started correctly. 
2) There is no space left and database is crashed / stopped working.

To correct, login to remote db and check if database is up or not and there is enough space for database to perform operations.

To check if database is open or not, on remote machine where db is installed, you can login with sql plus and run query to check status of database.

Comment: The question shows that the database is running, by connecting locally; so neither of those reasons applies. The issue is with trying to connect remotely - the command used hasn't been shown but appears to just be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Having `ORACLE_SID` set in your environment is only relevant for local connections. The error is telling you that there is no database running with that SID on the machine you are running SQL*Plus on. It doesn't know about the remote DB.

To connect remotely you need to tell SQL*Plus how to reach the remote DB, which is usually either via a TNS entry or using ['easy connect' syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/netag/configuring-naming-methods.html#GUID-B0437826-43C1-49EC-A94D-B650B6A4A6EE).

You haven't included any details of the remote DB, but you would need to do something like:

```
sqlplus username@//database_host:listener_port/remote_service_name
```

Or start with `sqlplus /nolog` and then use the `connect` command, as shown in the documentation.

The port is usually 1521 but might be different, and the service name *might* be the same as the SID. If you run `lsnrctl services` or `lsnrctl status` on the DB server you should be able to see the valid service names, as well as the address and port the listener is using.

Comment: The command you provided is exactly what I did, but it didn't work as well. I updated my post and included listeners status.